# ios - compiling code with UrbanAirship libraries gives "release not available" error

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I added UrbanAirship libraries to my code, and I am getting these kinds of error when compiling `UAPushSettingsAliasViewController.m` and `UAInboxMessageListCell.m` and a few similar classes. The errors happen on this method:

```
- (void)dealloc {

    RELEASE_SAFELY(tableView);
    RELEASE_SAFELY(aliasCell);
    RELEASE_SAFELY(textCell);
    RELEASE_SAFELY(textLabel);
    RELEASE_SAFELY(aliasField);

    [super dealloc];
}
```

and most of the errors are `"release not available: not available in automatic reference counting mode"`

Would anyone know why this is happening and how I can resolve this?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using features such as `dealloc`, `release` and `retain`, which aren't needed in ARC as it automatically manages memory. You can turn off ARC in build settings, or add `-fno-objc-arc` to the compiler flags on the files that don't use ARC.

In build settings
[image]

For the `-fno-objc-arc`, add it here

[image]

Add it by double clicking on compiler flags and add it for the files that contain things like `retain`, `autorelease`, `release`, and `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: thanks, how do I acc that -fno-objc-arc to the compiler flags

Comment: thank you, that fixed most of the problems. There are still a few errors in UABeveledLoadingIndicator.m - would you know why that didn't get resolved?

Comment: @Genadinik what are the errors?

Comment: It says ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'

Comment: It seems that just in that file those autorelease and dealloc issues didn't go away.

Comment: Are you sure that you put the compiler flag on all the files that don't use ARC?

Comment: No, I just put it on the ViewController which you have on your example :) Should I go through my Controllers and test which are using the dealloc thing?

Comment: Yea, the ViewController was just an example. You have to put that flag on any file that manually manages memory, and shouldn't put it on files that do use ARC, as that may cause a problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27047/discussion-between-genadinik-and-chris-loonam)